# dynamically change the class attribute

Tags: html, css, angularjs

My image is not coming at correct position when I am setting it dynamically with `margin-top`.

See the arrow pointing to the right (red color) in the below image which is what I want:

[image]

I have the following css:

```
.file_arrow_right {
        background: url('../images/right_icon.png') no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 35px;
        height: 22px;
        background-size: 18px;
        background-position: 0px;
        margin-top: -500px;
    }
```

I want to change only the `margin-top` of above CSS dynamically based on certain image height so I used the following-

```
app.controller('filePreviewSectionCtrl', 
function ($scope, $q, $sce, $rootScope, $filter, $compile, $timeout, $state, 
$modalInstance, commFile, blobUrl) {    
    var myBase64 = "data:"+commFile.fileType+";base64,"+commFile.image+"";
    //jpeg, .jpg, .bmp, .png, .txt
    if(commFile.fileType.split("/")[1] == "jpeg" || 
     commFile.fileType.split("/")[1] == "jpg" ||  
     commFile.fileType.split("/")[1] == "bmp" || 
     commFile.fileType.split("/")[1] == "png") {
        $scope.imgBlob = myBase64;

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = myBase64;
        img.addEventListener('load',function(){
            var width=img.width;
            var height=img.height;
            console.log("width: "+width);
            console.log("height: "+height);
            // should change dynamically
            $scope.arrowMarginTop = "margin-top: "+height/2+"px";
        });     
    } 
})
```

This is HTML:

```
       <script type="text/ng-template" id="filePreviewSectionCtrl.html">
        <div id="dynamicFile" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <span class= "file_arrow_right" ng-class="arrowMarginTop">
            </span>     
        </div>          
       </script>
```

**UPDATE:**

As per suggestion given by  @Temani that span already is inline element and it will not have any affect of margin-top, I changed the span to div. Then I used the @Satpal answer to dynamically change the CSS.

Comment: display:block or inline-block to the class ... you are using span element

Comment: @TemaniAfif. I want to change the right pointing arrow such that it comes to exact center right of left image. Since the left image can be of any height so I need to change the right pointing arrow margin-top attribute dynamically.

Comment: yes and you are targetting the span right ? which is an inline element and you cannot use margin-top with it

Comment: @TemaniAfif. OK, now I am using two divs side by side and using `float:left` on both divs. How to align the second divs arrow to the rightmost of the screen as shown in red circle in question?

Comment: no need float, but you can use positioning `position:absolute;right:0;top:calc(50% - 11px)` -- > this is for the right and you change left for the left. And make the parent `position:relative`

Comment: Thanks..it worked :) As per suggestion given by  @Temani that span already is inline element and it will not have any affect of margin-top, I changed the span to div. Then I used the Satpal answer to dynamically change the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are specifying the CSS rule in scope variable `arrowMarginTop`, You need to use [`ngStyle` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of `ngClass`

```
<span class= "file_arrow_right" ng-style="arrowMarginTop">
        </span>
```

Also set it up object

```
$scope.arrowMarginTop = { "margin-top" : height/2 + "px" };
```

Comment: @MyGod i don't think this will work as the issue is the span element where we cannot apply margin-top on it ... did this really solve your issue ? (nothing against you Satpal !)

Comment: @TemaniAfif. As per your suggestion that span already is inline element and it will not have any affect of margin-top, I changed the span to div. Then I used the Satpal answer to dynamically change the CSS.

Comment: @MyGod so in this case better make changes or add some comment to avoid any confusion from new comer :)